# What is eCpm Fill rate rpm

Tags: android, ios, admob

I have created ads for my app using admob-sdk. im getting revenue but i dont know what is `eCpm, fillrate, rpm` I've been searching the web but cant find the correct solution for this question..

Comment: This question is off-topic, it should not be asked here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are different ad mob metrics that help you measure how effective you app is at displaying ads

Ecpm = earnings per thousand requests

Fill rate = the percent of your requests that received ads (sometimes there are no ads to show)

Rpm = earnings per thousand requests (virtually the same as ecpm)

Comment: what is "request" ? is it ads being shown, or ads being clicked? Why would the "fill rate" not contain any ad ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper When you try to display an ad, your app sends a request for an ad to admob. If admob has an ad available when it receives your request, it sends an ad back, giving you an impression. Fill rate is pretty much `(impressions/requests)*100`.

Comment: But how do you get paid? by which event? by the clicks or the ads being shown? how is it calculated?

Comment: @androiddeveloper you get paid when someone clicks your ad. Admob don't reveal (as far as I can tell), how they work out your earnings.

Comment: so how would you know if Admob is any better than others? why would you care about all of the terminology if what actually care about is the money that you get?

Comment: ok, so you are saying there isn't a clear way to compare ad networks in terms of what you get, only of what the user gets...

Comment: I see. I know that it's already off topic, but can you tell me how the payment itself work too? I mean, how do they pay you?

Comment: do they pay every X days? or every X amount of money?

Comment: Thank you for your help. If you wish, you can check out my app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager

Comment: @android - also, you should delete all your comments below the first four (I will do the same) - just to keep the comments somewhat on topic

Comment: @jcw I am getting "No fill from any mediation ad networks" error. Before uploading its worked fine. I am new for the Ads integration.